# VMware port forwarding issues

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vmware

I am new to GNU/Linux. I want to host my own web server/website so that I can use it on my other devices on my home network (using WiFi). I don't know how to proceed. Can someone guide me?

I am on using Ubuntu as a VM(VMWare) and nodejs as my server. I want my VM to host the website so that I can access it on the host computer as well as on my home network.

What I have already done:

- Set up a nodejs server on localhost at port 3000
- Installed nginx and started nginx service as reverse proxy

When I open `192.168.221.128`, it works as intended on host computer. When I try to do the next part, it doesn't work. I have tried to forward port using Vmware's Virtual Network Editor.

VM's ip address: 192.168.221.128

VMWare NAT Settings

- Gateway IP: 192.168.221.2

Under Port Forwarding

- Host-Port: 3000
- Type: TCP
- VM IP Address: 192.168.221.128
- Port: 80

Answer (score 0):

> I am new to GNU/Linux. I want to host my own web server/website so
> that I can use it on my other devices on my home network (using WiFi).
> .... VMWare NAT Settings Gateway IP: 192.168.221.2

To reach your Virtual Machine from outside, you cannot use NAT (Internal Network Address Translation) for your Guest Setting. (NAT is VMware Default).

Go into the Guest Settings (Guest needs to be shut down) and change Networking from NAT to Bridged.

Start your Guest and now the Guest IP is on your main Router (that also serves your Host).  You need to make the Guest IP Static on the Router so outside people can find it.

This setup will work for the Host wired or wireless router connection.

Comment: When I change it to Bridge mode internet doesn't work.

Comment: That is very strange. Have you got a VPN stopping internet?   Did you restart your guest?   Make another quick Guest machine and see if Internet works with that. Bridged Networking is very simple.  Try as above and see.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that.